# "Recorded on it" as a subject

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, subjects

I am unsure if the phrase "Recorded on it" can be used as a subject.

> He found a blueprint. Recorded on it was a device used by the Order.

Does this sound grammatically correct?

Comment: A device recorded on a blueprint?

Comment: This is an inversion. Your subject is "a device..."

Comment: Your example contains inversion of the subject, "a device used by the Order",                and the complement clause "recorded on it". The basic version is "A device used by the order was recorded on it". Whatever that means!

Comment: The focus in this question is a bit different but it may help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/566217/participle-phrases-and-inversion

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, how do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: @StuartF The link was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Xanne I guess *device* is used here in the sense of *symbol*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Recorded on it was a device used by the Order.*

Your example contains inversion of the subject, "a device used by the Order", and the complement clause "recorded on it".

The basic (non-inverted) version is

> *A device used by the order was recorded on it.*

Comment: It is worth adding that one way of giving special emphasis to one or another part of a sentence is change the order as in the example given.  The standard order of an English sentence is to start with the subject (what or whom the sentence as about); then the verb followed by the object (if any), which tell us the point of the sentence - what it has to say about the subject.  Reversing the order makes us wait for the subject and so gives emphasis to it. So "Recorded on it was..." keeps us in suspense a little.

Comment: @Tuffy I'm aware of that. I dealt with the grammar, which is what the OP specifically asked about.